# Is NP-complete the existence of paths of a given length in a directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness

Given a directed graph G= (V,E), a pair of vertices s and t, a natural number K encoded in binary, whether the problem to decide there exists a path (**not necessarily simple**) from s to t of length K is NP-complete ?

Comment: It is in P: compute the $K$th power of the adjacency matrix by repeated squaring, capping all entries by $1$.

Comment: You can also simply do a BFS starting from vertex $s$ and check if you reach $t$ in $K$ steps or not.